# Java package inheritance, simple query

Tags: java, inheritance, package

I am new to [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and Java programming. I was practicing inheritance with sample code and I was wondering if there is any access modifier that will allow the variable to be accessed by methods in the same package.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Found the answer. Package modifier does the trick.

Comment: I know default modifier does the trick but what about a package modifier?

Comment: what do you mean by "a package modifier"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

default modifier, in other words, no modifier (not public, not private, and not protected):

```
void doSomething() {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that =) even found that "package" modifier does the trick

Comment: @Jay, did you mean protected modifier?  there is no _package_ modifier.

Comment: LOL what?

http://download.oracle.com/javafx/1.3/tutorials/core/modifiers/#package heres the link

Comment: The rules are different in Javafx than in normal Java.  The package modifier in Javafx  is more or less the same as the default in Java.